# Adding up a list based off a dictionary parameter

Tags: python

I am working with a dictionary that is structured similarly:

```py
bbb_dct = {
       "gender": ["F", "M", "F", "O", "M", "M", "M", "F"], 
        "cost": [1, 20, 455, 4, 2424, 65, 423, 23]
}
```

I am trying to add up all of the values associated with the "cost" key for each gender level (F, M, O). I am looking for the following output:

```
{'O': 4}
{'F': 479}
{'M': 2932}
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
for g in set(bbb_dct["gender"]):
    if g == "F":
        x = sum(bbb_dct["cost"])
    elif g == "M":
        x = sum(bbb_dct["cost"])
    else:
        x = sum(bbb_dct["cost"])
    {g:x}
```

However, this is only giving me the total cost for all data points, as seen below:

```
{'O': 3415}
{'F': 3415}
{'M': 3415}
```

How can I make it so I am adding up only the costs associated with each gender level?

**Possible Solution:** May be I need to change the code inside the if statements some how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip()` your two lists together so they're paired properly, then iterate over the pairs, adding to the dictionary if the key is present, or initializing at 0 and then adding `cost`:

```py
bbb_dct = {"gender": ["F", "M", "F", "O", "M", "M", "M", "F"],
           "cost": [1, 20, 45, 5, 4, 2424, 65, 423, 23]}

costs = {}
for gender, cost in zip(bbb_dct["gender"], bbb_dct["cost"]):
    costs[gender] = costs.get(gender, 0) + cost

print(costs)
# {'F': 479, 'M': 2932, 'O': 4}
```

EDIT: the previous top answer was a good answer and I'm not sure why it was deleted. It used `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
import collections

costs = collections.defaultdict(int)
for gender, cost in zip(bbb_dct["gender"], bbb_dct["cost"]):
    costs[gender] += cost

print(costs)
# {'F': 479, 'M': 2932, 'O': 4}
```

Here's another solution using `collections.Counter`:

```py
import collections

gender = bbb_dct["gender"]
cost = bbb_dct["cost"]
costs = Counter("".join(c*g for c, g in zip(cost, gender)))

print(costs)
# {'F': 479, 'M': 2932, 'O': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fan of [pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) library in python, then the following code might help

```
agg = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bbb_dct).groupby("gender").sum()
result = agg.to_dict(orient="dict")['cost']
```

**Edit**
Also let me explain why your code doesn't work.

You are finding the sum of `bbb_dct["cost"]` everytime irrespective of the if condition. Now ask yourself

1. Why do I need multiple if statements when the code inside the if is always the same?
2. The `bbb_dct["cost"]` statement has values for every gender. So if I do the sum, I would get the sum of all the genders every time. Is that what I need?

So the problem is that you are using if statement conditions but you are not filtering the values of `bbb_dct["cost"]` based on the gender. That's why you get the complete sum.

Comment: Suggesting a large third party package for such a simple task isn't ideal...

Comment: That's not true. Manual loops are not as optimised and libraries like pandas and numpy. Try running a benchmark

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with performance. Of course Pandas is faster, it's backed by NumPy. My point is that Pandas is huge, and not everybody needs or wants to import such a massive library for something this trivial. I'd even argue that it's bad practice as it is introducing unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: @blorgon Well that subjective and I would rather not comment on it

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

bbb_dct = {"gender": ["F", "M", "F", "O", "M", "M", "M", "F"], "cost": [1, 20, 455, 4, 2424, 65, 423, 23]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bbb_dct).groupby('gender').agg(sum)
print(df)

        cost
gender      
F        479
M       2932
O          4
```

Then if you need the result as a new dictionary:

```
bbb_dict_sum = df.to_dict()
print(bbb_dict_sum)

{'cost': {'F': 479, 'M': 2932, 'O': 4}}
```

Comment: Suggesting a large third party package for such a simple task isn't ideal...

Comment: We don't really have much context for this question's specific use case. If the actual dictionary the OP is using is much larger and requires more manipulation, maybe working with a pandas dataframe might be a good idea.